# How can i plot different plots for indexes of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm new to pandas and trying to learn and ran into this problem.
I've a dataframe and I am trying to plot the rows of the dataframe for each index value. I want different plots (subplots) for each index in the dataframe.

```
ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS   264296  32413   80984   1286    338 31  564 669
ARUNACHAL PRADESH   401876  27045   418732  3287    162815  771 362553  6648
CHANDIGARH  852574  51447   8720    138329  1160    1960    246 1014
```

Here the string values are the indexes and i want different plots for these indexes of the dataframe.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you you need is `T` for transpose and `plot` with parameter `subplots=True`:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                1      2       3       4       5     6       7     8
0                                                                                   
ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS  264296  32413   80984    1286     338    31     564   669
ARUNACHAL PRADESH          401876  27045  418732    3287  162815   771  362553  6648
CHANDIGARH                 852574  51447    8720  138329    1160  1960     246  1014
```

Where column 0 is in your index which contains locations.

The use df.T to transpose the dataframe in to a "column" format vs "rows".

```
d.T
```

Output:

```
0  ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS  ARUNACHAL PRADESH  CHANDIGARH
1                     264296             401876      852574
2                      32413              27045       51447
3                      80984             418732        8720
4                       1286               3287      138329
5                        338             162815        1160
6                         31                771        1960
7                        564             362553         246
8                        669               6648        1014
```

And, now let's generate plots:

```
df.T.plot(subplots=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS": [264296, 32413, 80984, 1286, 338, 31,  564, 669],
                   "ARUNACHAL PRADESH": [401876, 27045, 418732, 3287, 162815, 771, 362553, 6648],
                   "CHANDIGARH": [852574, 51447, 8720, 138329, 1160, 1960, 246, 1014]})
data.plot()
plt.show()
```

with columns labels:

```
data.index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
data.plot(xticks=range(len(data.index)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can i make use of the column names that i have for the integer values so that a legend is automatically generated